# I try to override materialUI inbuilt classes using CSS file, styles are applying all the components in React how to stop overriding styles globally?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

**TableOne.css**

```
 @media (min-width:601px) and (max-width: 960px) {
      .MuiTable-root  .MuiTableBody-root{
          display: flex !important;
          justify-content: center !important ;
          flex-wrap: wrap !important; 
          row-gap: 15px;
      }
    }
```

```
**above styles are applying to all the tables present in all my React components. But I want to apply for table that present in specific component. How I can write specific .css file for specific component**
```

- I am trying to access the inbuilt materialUI classes and applying styles so, styles are affecting globally how I can stop affecting styles over all the components in React JS *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you write global CSS like that, it gets applied to the whole document. Instead, you can take advantage of [theming](https://mui.com/customization/theming/) in `@mui/material`.
2. Use `createTheme` from `@mui/material/styles` to define the theme and `ThemeProvider` to apply that theme. And instead of using plain media queries, use [theme breakpoints](https://mui.com/customization/breakpoints/) instead but you will have to specify the pixel values for these breakpoints yourself if you're not using the default ones. It can be done using theming as well.

```js
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
let theme = createTheme();
theme = createTheme(theme, {
  components: {
    MuiTableBody: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          "@media (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 960px)": {
            // your styles here
          },
          [theme.breakpoints.between("md", "lg")]: {
            // use this instead
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
export default theme;
```

3. In your component, wrap your `Table` component with `ThemeProvider`

```js
import Table from "./components/Table";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import theme from "./theme/MuiTable"; // this is the theme you created above
...
const App = props => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Table />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is a [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-darwin-g4yg1)